# How add images over another image and display in in a grid fashion?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have a larger image[A4 size], i have a small images[say size of the atm card], I want put all the images[may be 5-6 images] into the large image in gridview fashion shown in my below diagram.

[image]

My code looks like this... But this adds only one row of image.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(884, 1020);
        int k = 33, j = 33;
        for (int i = 1; i < 11;i++ )
        {

            using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                canvas.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(k, j, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), new Rectangle(10, 10, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                canvas.Save();

                canvas.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(k+460, j, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), new Rectangle(10, 10, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                canvas.Save();
            }
        }
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\LargePic.png");
        BigPic.Image = bitmap as Image;
```

Comment: Can you show me some more example including Grid , Images ? I don't understand your Question :(

Comment: In my images those small colored boxes are my small images[which are of fixed size]. I want to add those images into the larger image in the grid fashion shown as in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QL9Dt/1/)

```
<div id="GridViewContainer">
    <div class="grids"><img src="http://kristamoore.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/yes-man1.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="grids"><img src="http://kristamoore.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/yes-man1.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="grids"><img src="http://kristamoore.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/yes-man1.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="grids"><img src="http://kristamoore.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/yes-man1.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="grids"><img src="http://kristamoore.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/yes-man1.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#GridViewContainer{
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:cyan;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#GridViewContainer div{
    width:35%;
    height:35%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:green;
}


.grids{

    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top:10%;


}
.grids img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `ListView` instead of `GridView` .
Add your Image to `ListView` and show them as Thumbnails or Gallery .
See this [Code Project Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43265/ImageListView) !